# How to put an object to the upper middle in the resume

Tags: latex

I used TexShop and Mac to create my resume.
The code I used was referring to the GitHub as below:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/sb2nov/resume/blob/master/sourabh_bajaj_resume.tex)

My question is now I would like to add "Objective: ____ Internship" 
in the upper middle position and the font is about the same big as my name. It should be between my name and the "Email" section but on the same level as my name is.

My text code is as below:

```
   \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{https://github.com/jenli810006995}
   {\Large Jen-Li Chen}} 
    \hfill
      \textbf{Objective: Internship}& Email : \href{mailto:jc3992@rit.edu}{jc3992@rit.edu} \\
```

The outfit looked like the picture below:
[image]

Any suggestions for me to put the "   Internship" to the middle top in the resume? Now the " " is not there because I cropped it.
Thank you all in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to obtain something like that:

[image: compilation output]

For this you can add a third column to the table like this:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llr}
  {\Large\textbf{\href{https://github.com/jenli810006995}{Jen-Li Chen}}} \textbf{Objective:} & {\Large\textbf{Internship}} & Email : \href{mailto:jc3992@rit.edu}{jc3992@rit.edu} \\
  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/jenlichen}{https://www.linkedin.com/in/jenlichen} &&\\
  \href{https://github.com/jenli810006995}{https://github.com/jenli810006995} &&\\
\end{tabular*}
```

Or, if you want "Intership" to be at the **exact** center of the page like this:

[image: pdf output]

Then I don't know how to do it with the table, but you can use the following trick: write "Intership" at the center of a line and then write the table over the line:

```
\centering{\Large\textbf{Internship}}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{https://github.com/jenli810006995}{\Large Jen-Li Chen}} \textbf{Objective:}& Email : \href{mailto:jc3992@rit.edu}{jc3992@rit.edu} \\
  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/jenlichen}{https://www.linkedin.com/in/jenlichen} &\\
  \href{https://github.com/jenli810006995}{https://github.com/jenli810006995} &\\
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I hope to move the "objective" to the middle too. But I will try your suggestions!!! Thank you very much!!!